# Using ajax in laravel with cors

Tags: ajax, laravel, phonegap, html-framework-7

for two days searching and trying to solve my issue i couldn't find solution

i want to make laravel ajax login

i make request using get and it worked but not work when i use post method

i will list back-end and front-end in the two cases

///// back end

////// laravel routes :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','cors'],'prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    /*Route::get('login', function () {
        echo '*****';
    });*/
    Route::post('register', 'APIController@register');
/// the routes i'm testing
    Route::post('login', 'APIController@login');
    Route::get('login', 'APIController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt-auth'], function () {
        Route::post('get_user_details', 'APIController@get_user_details');
    });
});
```

/// laravel middlware cors

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, Application, Accept'
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

here's get response from chrome

```
Request URL:http://192.168.1.7/cart/public/api/login?email=a%40y.com&password=EN%40123456!
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.1.7:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, Application, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:273
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 04 Feb 2018 15:35:42 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2m PHP/7.1.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Set-Cookie:cartmob_session=eyJpdiI6InF5UG9MVjVqemZFc1JUTnA5c2hDT1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUWlneGRVZUFvVm02ZERKTFcyV21tNTRUNXlcLytFaFwvKzdKSXhQY2NiMDhVNEJTanRCMTFuQ29oOEVTVWZ0cHFVU3IxUkhENlNMSDlCM2ZHaHpSXC8xN2c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjZmYmYxNjBmODE3MWViNTkyMTY1YWViZWYxZDEzN2E4OTJhMDAyMjk1ZDg0YThkMzczZTdiMDhiYmYzNjQxZjgifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sun, 04-Feb-2018 17:35:42 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InNzb3djY3o5b1p4Q29tZFRHZGRkcWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibkkrcGxhcTlSUTVGMWtLOUJtZkRRNkpCRmJNczhcL3pVXC9kNU5ZNnFjeUVhNWJ5RFhab0hyYWZ3dGMxSlNLUFh4ZE9NeEJGRVE5MlRoK29VZG9KTmFGdz09IiwibWFjIjoiMzY3NjM2YTEwOGY2MTZhYjM5YzY4OWU3OTQyM2Q2YTJjYjhkMzVhN2EyMzdhMTdmYjU2MDk1ZTIyMDY0ZTFlZSJ9; expires=Sun, 04-Feb-2018 17:35:42 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.11
X-RateLimit-Limit:60
X-RateLimit-Remaining:59
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ar,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.1.7
Origin:http://192.168.1.7:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://192.168.1.7:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
email:a@y.com
password:EN@123456!
```

///// front end

```
   var data = {
                    email: 'a@y.com',
                    password: 'EN@123456!'
                }
                    app.request({
                        url: 'http://192.168.1.7/cart/public/api/login',
                        method: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json',

                        data: data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('success')
                            alert(response)
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status) {
                            alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                            alert('ErrorStatus: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
                        }
                    });
```

/// post

```
var data = {
                    email: 'a@y.com',
                    password: 'EN@123456!'

                }
                app.request({
                    url: 'http://192.168.1.7/cart/public/api/login',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('success')
                        alert(response)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                        alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                        alert('ErrorStatus: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
                    }
                });

/////////// response : 

Request URL:http://192.168.1.7/cart/public/api/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:192.168.1.7:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 04 Feb 2018 15:51:26 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2m PHP/7.1.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Set-Cookie:cartmob_session=eyJpdiI6IjJyanNZUGMwSEo4bEd3U0NxMkF6bUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWURtRkVhREtaQUd4dXo2K3dsQkUyQXJHSU9NU255bUo0NnFzNjNLbHNCRngxT0lqOFBBUGZaTEJEOTlMNmU0UHdraTdzK2ptZ0psQ0x5QSsrVDFkbWc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjlmMWYzZjA3NjQ1YmRmMDhmMGM0YTY2ZmQ0YTRiNjM1MGFhNDdkZWI5NGVmZDRiNzFiNTI0NDg0MTBhMmUzMzkifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sun, 04-Feb-2018 17:51:26 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.11
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ar,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:37
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:192.168.1.7
Origin:http://192.168.1.7:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://192.168.1.7:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
email:a@y.com
password:EN@123456!
```

that's every thing

till now i couldn't find the solution

Comment: this the tutorial i have followed with some modifications 
https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-api-using-jwt-authentication-tutorial-from-scratch-exampleexample.html

Comment: `return Response::make('OK', 404, $headers);` why are you 404ing the preflight?

Comment: i was trying to check that line could have any effect have any effects  but i forget to return back to be same as tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web server doesn't allow POST requests:

`Status Code:500 Internal Server Error`

It doesn't look like it has anything to do with CORS.